# Laravel Eloquent Eager Load from Multiple Table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm relatively new to Laravel and only recently started to learn about eager loading. 
Currently, I have a project in which I was required to develop an app for connection between companies and partners.

Connection can either be between company-company, partner-partner or company-partner. For now, I stored all the connections in one **Connection** table as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP66g.png):

In **Connection** class, I use polymorphic to retrieve all the connections for a company/partner:

```
public function connectable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And this function in **Partner** and **Company** classes:

```
public function my_connection()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Connection::class, 'connectable', 'model_type', 'model_id');
}
```

I can retrieve the list of connections just fine, but problem arise when I want to get the details for each connected company/partner. I want to use eager load in **Connection** class as below but it only manage to either get from company or partner but not both

```
protected $with = [
    'following'
];

public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'connect_to', 'id');
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Or should I separate company and partner connections into different tables?

**Edit**: By connection, I meant a partner or company can connect/follow each other like the usual social media app. It wasn't mutual tho. Say, if Partner A follow Partner B, then only that connection will be stored. Partner B is still considered not connected to A.

Comment: I am not sure when you say connection. Do you mean relationship between partner and company? If it is then you can have one to one relationship and also makes your code read a lot better

Comment: It's like a social media app, where company and partner can follow each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly which model do you want to eager load (i.e. `model_type` or `connect_type`), but in either case you can use a `morphTo` relation, as in:

```
public function following()
    {
        return $this->morphTo(null, $type = 'connect_type', $id = 'connect_to');
    }
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Works like charm. Thank you so much! I originally wanted to load from connect_type, but your method also works for model_type. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)